# How to try different effect sizes for Fisher's exact test?

Tags: r, simulation, inference, hypothesis-test

I am currently working on a simulation, and I would like to see what happens  if the effect size is different. How would I test out different effect sizes for the Fisher's exact test with my current code?

```
  # p1<-response in controls
  # p2<-response in treated
  # Generating random deviates from a Uniform(0,1) distribution
  control.year1<-(runif(16, min = 0, max = 1))
  treat.year1<-(runif(16, min = 0, max = 1))

  #Generating dichotomous response variables for each group
  control.respond1<-ifelse(control.year1<=0.05,1,0)
  treat.respond1<-ifelse(treat.year1<=0.30,1,0)

  #Summing number of responses from each group
  control.no1<-sum(control.respond1==0)
  control.yes1<-sum(control.respond1==1)
  treat.no1<-sum(treat.respond1==0)
  treat.yes1<-sum(treat.respond1==1)

  #Perform the Fisher's exact test (one sided) with p<=0.01
  fisher<-
  matrix(c(control.no1,control.yes1,treat.no1,treat.yes1),nrow=2,ncol=2)
   f<-fisher.test(fisher,alternative = "greater")
```

Comment: Question might be better suited on the "Cross Validate" site

Comment: Link to site mentioned by @Dave2e is https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Dave2e thanks, I will post on there instead.